# Moving a instantiated gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I want to change the position of a `instantiated game object`. For that I have used a `UI button` when the user clicks on the button a cube will be `instantiated` and when user clicks on that instantiated cube and move a `UI slider`, the position of that cube will be changed according to the value given by the slider.

[image]

I tried this way but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class instantiate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cube;
    public float speed = 0f;
    public float pos = 0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100.0f))
            {
                Debug.Log("Clicked");

                if (hit.collider.tag == "Cube")
                {

                    // Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);

                    // Destroy(this);
                    speed += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
                    hit.collider.gameObject.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, speed);
                    hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, pos);//pos
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void objinst()
    {
        Instantiate(cube, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    }

    public void rotatess(float newspeed)
    {
        speed = newspeed;

    }

    public void positions(float newpos)
    {

        pos = newpos;
    }
}
```

Comment: What axis do you want to move the object when sliding it?

Comment: @Programmer Z axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to have a callback function that gets called when the `Button` is clicked and another one that gets called when the `Slider` value changes. I can't tell if you are doing this from the Editor but the way your functions are named, we can't tell which is one being called during `Button` click or `Slider` value change...

Put your `Instantiate` code in your `Button` callback function then put your cube moving code in the `Slider` value change callback function.

In your `Raycast` code that detects the cube click, store the `Transform` reference of the cube to a global `Transform`  variable. This stored `Transform`  is what you will use to move the cube in your `Slider` value change callback function.

You subscribe to `Button` click event with `Button.onClick.AddListener(instantiateButtonCallBackFunction);` then to Slider value change event with `Slider.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { sliderCallBackFunction(cubeSlider.value); });`

Here is what it should look like. Everything is done with code. Simply drag the Cube prefab, `Slider` and  `Button` to the right slot and it should work. When a `Button` is clicked, Cube is instantiated. When the cube is clicked, you will be able to move it with the slider.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class instantiate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cubePrefab;
    public Slider cubeSlider;
    public Button instantiateButton;

    public float speed = 0f;
    public float pos = 0f;


    private Transform currentObjectToDrag = null;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //Set Slider Values
        cubeSlider.minValue = 0f;
        cubeSlider.maxValue = 50f;
        cubeSlider.value = 0f;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000.0f))
            {
                GameObject objHit = hit.collider.gameObject;
                Debug.Log("We Clicked on : " + objHit.name);

                //Check if this is cube
                if (objHit.CompareTag("Cube"))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Cube selected. You can now drag the Cube with the Slider!");
                    //Change the current GameObject to drag
                    currentObjectToDrag = objHit.transform;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void instantiateCube()
    {
        //Instantiate(cubePrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate(cubePrefab, new Vector3(-15.1281f, 0.67f, 7.978208f), Quaternion.identity);
    }

    public void rotatess(float newspeed)
    {
        speed = newspeed;

    }

    public void positions(float newpos)
    {
        pos = newpos;
    }

    //Called when Instantiate Button is clicked
    void instantiateButtonCallBack()
    {
        Debug.Log("Instantiate Button Clicked!");
        instantiateCube();
    }

    //Called when Slider value changes
    void sliderCallBack(float value)
    {
        Debug.Log("Slider Value Moved : " + value);

        //Move the Selected GameObject in the Z axis with value from Slider
        if (currentObjectToDrag != null)
        {
            currentObjectToDrag.position = new Vector3(0, 0, value);
            Debug.Log("Position changed!");
        }
    }

    //Subscribe to Button and Slider events
    void OnEnable()
    {
        instantiateButton.onClick.AddListener(instantiateButtonCallBack);
        cubeSlider.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { sliderCallBack(cubeSlider.value); });
    }

    //Un-Subscribe to Button and Slider events
    void OnDisable()
    {
        instantiateButton.onClick.RemoveListener(instantiateButtonCallBack);
        cubeSlider.onValueChanged.RemoveListener(delegate { sliderCallBack(cubeSlider.value); });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I got the Idea well explained

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a reference to the instance you've created.

```
GameObject myCube = Instantiate(cube, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
```

You can then control the position of it using that reference.

```
myCube.transform.position.x = 10;
```